# Hibernate Search: groupby and in clause

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

What are the equilivalent of the **groupby** and **In** SQL clause in an Hibernate Search Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. If you need to group the hits after a query, then you probably queried the wrong index. If I remember correctly your last question was about a product that has multiple prices, and you were querying the prices, which index-embed the product. Try the opposite: query the product, and index-embed the prices.

If your problem is that only one of the prices is actually relevant to a particular user, and you need to filter out other prices, then you need [nested search](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-storage), and that is only available starting with [Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started).

If all you need is a count of hits grouped by category, then you might be interested in Hibernate Search 6's [aggregations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-aggregation). They are available in Hibernate Search 5 too, but with a different API, and they are named [facets](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-faceting) and are more limited (no support for multi-valued fields in particular).